# php 7.4 выводит ошибку при запросе $_COOKIE

Tags: php

При попытке получить данные из куки которых нет выдает ошибку:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uid in D:\xampp\htdocs\header.php on line 9
```

Пытался исправить так:

```
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0)
{
    $id = $_COOKIE['uid'];
}
```

Что делать?

```
if(count($_COOKIE) > count($_COOKIE))
{
    $id = $_COOKIE['uid'];
}
```

так тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $_COOKIE['uid'] ?? null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
    $id = $_COOKIE['uid'];
}
```

Проверяем что кука существует и если она есть записываем её в переменную $id

Comment: Благодарю вас )